# при нажатии на ссылку, чтоб страница не поднималась вверх

Tags: javascript, html, css

В меню пункты категорий имеют решетки "#" и из--за этого при нажатии человека перекидывает вверх страницы.
Нашел, что это убирается при помощи добавления `onclick="return false"`:

```
< a href="#" onclick="return false" > link < /a>
```

Скажите, как исправить не добавляя к каждой ссылке с решеткой onclick, а прописав правило один раз?
Например, в js для сылок внутри класса такого-то. Или как-то по-другому.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("a[href='#']").forEach(el => { el.addEventListener("click", () => 0); })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил вариант с делегированием клика на `document` и там проверку

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).click((e) => {
    const {target} = e;
    if(target.nodeName === 'A' && target.getAttribute('href') === '#') {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='#'>Ссылка 1</a>
<a href='#'>Ссылка 2</a>
<a href='#'>Ссылка 3</a>
<a href='#'>Ссылка 4</a>
<a href='#'>Ссылка 5</a>
<a href='#'>Ссылка 6</a>
<a href='#'>Ссылка 7</a>
<a href='#'>Ссылка 8</a>
<a href='#'>Ссылка 9</a>
<a href='#'>Ссылка 10</a>
```

Будет работать для всех ссылок с `href=#`, даже если ссылки добавились после загрузки документа

Comment: что-то никак на Ваш код не среагировало. я его ввставляю в js файл внутрь $(function() { ...... });

Comment: @ВадимШорохов поправил ответ

Comment: работает, спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

```
link = document.querySelector("a[href=#]");
function stopAnchor(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
link.onclick = stopAnchor;
```